# Section ListView in DIalog with "simple_list_item_multiple_choice"

Tags: android, listview, dialog, sections

So im using the commonsware example of sectioned listviews,[here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/ListView/Sections/src/com/commonsware/android/listview/SectionedDemo.java), but i use the multiselection option. The problem is when i get the getCheckedItemPositions(), if i have selected from the second section or above the positions dont really match. Seems that the Section Headers count as a position, so im having a problem of getting the checked items from the second,third...sections.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` is the one keeping track of checked states, not the `ListAdapter`. Even the `MergeAdapter` does not really know what are headers and what are not -- they're all just contents to it.

You could extend (or replace) `MergeAdapter` with something that knew concretely the difference between headers and detail rows. That adapter could give you a method to convert an absolute position (what `ListView` reports in `getCheckedItemPositions()`) into a section and position within that section.

Also, for support on the CommonsWare books, open source code, and such, I recommend the [cw-android](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android) Google Group.

Comment: you're talking about the adapters added to the SectionAdapter in the method addSection?